# C# add nodes in OPC UA Server while running

Tags: c#, opc-ua

Is it possible to add nodes while the OPC UA Server is running?
I succeed adding nodes before the server started by using AddPredefinedNode() method by Opc.Ua.Server library, CustomNodeManager2 class. I can read my sample data node with any OPC UA Client. Here is the sample code about adding nodes before the server run.

```
public override void CreateAddressSpace( IDictionary<NodeId, IList<IReference>> externalReferences )
        {
            lock (Lock)
            {
                LoadPredefinedNodes( SystemContext, externalReferences );

                IList<IReference> references = null;

                if (!externalReferences.TryGetValue( ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder, out references ))
                {
                    externalReferences[ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder] = references = new List<IReference>( );
                }

                
                //FolderState rootMy = CreateFolder( null, "Machines" );
                //rootMy.AddReference( ReferenceTypes.Organizes, true, ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder );
                //references.Add( new NodeStateReference( ReferenceTypes.Organizes, false, rootMy.NodeId ) );
                //rootMy.EventNotifier = EventNotifiers.SubscribeToEvents;
                //AddRootNotifier( rootMy );

                //string[] machines = new string[] { "Machine A", "Machine B", "Machine C" };
                //list = new List<BaseDataVariableState<int>>( );

                //for (int i = 0; i < machines.Length; i++)
                //{
                //    FolderState myFolder = CreateFolder( rootMy, machines[i] );

                //    CreateVariable( myFolder, "Name", DataTypeIds.String, ValueRanks.Scalar, "测试数据" ).Description = "设备的名称";
                //    CreateVariable( myFolder, "IsFault", DataTypeIds.Boolean, ValueRanks.Scalar, true ).Description = "设备是否启动";
                //    CreateVariable( myFolder, "TestValueFloat", DataTypeIds.Float, ValueRanks.Scalar, 100.5f );
                //    CreateVariable( myFolder, "AlarmTime", DataTypeIds.DateTime, ValueRanks.Scalar, DateTime.Now );
                //    list.Add( CreateVariable( myFolder, "TestValueInt", DataTypeIds.Int32, ValueRanks.Scalar, 47123 ) );




                //    #region Add Method

                //    MethodState addMethod = CreateMethod( myFolder, "Calculate" );
                //    // set input arguments
                //    addMethod.InputArguments = new PropertyState<Argument[]>( addMethod )
                //    {
                //        NodeId = new NodeId( addMethod.BrowseName.Name + "InArgs", NamespaceIndex ),
                //        BrowseName = BrowseNames.InputArguments
                //    };
                //    addMethod.InputArguments.DisplayName = addMethod.InputArguments.BrowseName.Name;
                //    addMethod.InputArguments.TypeDefinitionId = VariableTypeIds.PropertyType;
                //    addMethod.InputArguments.ReferenceTypeId = ReferenceTypeIds.HasProperty;
                //    addMethod.InputArguments.DataType = DataTypeIds.Argument;
                //    addMethod.InputArguments.ValueRank = ValueRanks.OneDimension;

                //    addMethod.InputArguments.Value = new Argument[]
                //    {
                //        new Argument() { Name = "Int32 value", Description = "Int32 value",  DataType = DataTypeIds.Int32, ValueRank = ValueRanks.Scalar },
                //        new Argument() { Name = "Int32 value", Description = "Int32 value",  DataType = DataTypeIds.Int32, ValueRank = ValueRanks.Scalar }
                //    };

                //    // set output arguments
                //    addMethod.OutputArguments = new PropertyState<Argument[]>( addMethod );
                //    addMethod.OutputArguments.NodeId = new NodeId( addMethod.BrowseName.Name + "OutArgs", NamespaceIndex );
                //    addMethod.OutputArguments.BrowseName = BrowseNames.OutputArguments;
                //    addMethod.OutputArguments.DisplayName = addMethod.OutputArguments.BrowseName.Name;
                //    addMethod.OutputArguments.TypeDefinitionId = VariableTypeIds.PropertyType;
                //    addMethod.OutputArguments.ReferenceTypeId = ReferenceTypeIds.HasProperty;
                //    addMethod.OutputArguments.DataType = DataTypeIds.Argument;
                //    addMethod.OutputArguments.ValueRank = ValueRanks.OneDimension;

                //    addMethod.OutputArguments.Value = new Argument[]
                //    {
                //        new Argument() { Name = "Operater Result", Description = "Operater Result",  DataType = DataTypeIds.String, ValueRank = ValueRanks.Scalar }
                //    };
                //    addMethod.OnCallMethod = new GenericMethodCalledEventHandler( OnAddCall );

                //    #endregion

                //}

                //SystemState = CreateVariable( rootMy, "Enable", DataTypeIds.Boolean, ValueRanks.Scalar, false );

                //CreateVariable( rootMy, "Mat", DataTypeIds.Double, ValueRanks.TwoDimensions, new double[4, 4] );


                //AddPredefinedNode( SystemContext, rootMy );



                //FolderState robots = CreateFolder( null, "Robots" );
                //robots.AddReference( ReferenceTypes.Organizes, true, ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder );
                //references.Add( new NodeStateReference( ReferenceTypes.Organizes, false, robots.NodeId ) );
                //robots.EventNotifier = EventNotifiers.SubscribeToEvents;
                //AddRootNotifier( robots );

                

                //AddPredefinedNode( SystemContext, robots );

                //생성 테스트

                FolderState tag = CreateFolder(null, "youhost");
                tag.AddReference(ReferenceTypes.Organizes, true, ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder);
                references.Add(new NodeStateReference(ReferenceTypes.Organizes, false, tag.NodeId));
                tag.EventNotifier = EventNotifiers.SubscribeToEvents;
                AddRootNotifier(tag);

                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    CreateVariable(tag, "Test"+i, DataTypeIds.Integer, ValueRanks.Scalar, 100 );
                }

                AddPredefinedNode(SystemContext, tag);

                FolderState tag2 = CreateFolder(null, "youhost2");
                tag2.AddReference(ReferenceTypes.Organizes, true, ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder);
                references.Add(new NodeStateReference(ReferenceTypes.Organizes, false, tag2.NodeId));
                tag2.EventNotifier = EventNotifiers.SubscribeToEvents;
                AddRootNotifier(tag2);

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    CreateVariable(tag2, "Test2_" + i, DataTypeIds.Integer, ValueRanks.Scalar, 1000);
                }
                
                AddPredefinedNode(SystemContext, tag2);

                //생성 테스트 2

                //FolderState test = CreateFolder(null, "test");
                //test.AddReference(ReferenceTypes.Organizes, true, ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder);
                //references.Add(new NodeStateReference(ReferenceTypes.Organizes, false, test.NodeId));
                //test.EventNotifier = EventNotifiers.SubscribeToEvents;
                //AddRootNotifier(test);

                //CreateNode(SystemContext, ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder, ReferenceTypes.Organizes, "testing", test);
            }
        }
```

However, there is no example or method about adding nodes while the server is running. I want to make system that get data from other process by MQTT or Socket ..etc and add them to the OPC UA Server with nodes structure.

I tried to add nodes from the client with AddNodes() method by Opc.Ua library, SessionClient class.
Here is the example about it.

```
public virtual ResponseHeader AddNodes(RequestHeader requestHeader, AddNodesItemCollection nodesToAdd, out AddNodesResultCollection results, out DiagnosticInfoCollection diagnosticInfos)
        {
            AddNodesRequest addNodesRequest = new AddNodesRequest();
            AddNodesResponse addNodesResponse = null;
            addNodesRequest.RequestHeader = requestHeader;
            addNodesRequest.NodesToAdd = nodesToAdd;
            UpdateRequestHeader(addNodesRequest, requestHeader == null, "AddNodes");
            try
            {
                if (base.UseTransportChannel)
                {
                    IServiceResponse serviceResponse = base.TransportChannel.SendRequest(addNodesRequest);
                    if (serviceResponse == null)
                    {
                        throw new ServiceResultException(2148073472u);
                    }

                    ClientBase.ValidateResponse(serviceResponse.ResponseHeader);
                    addNodesResponse = (AddNodesResponse)serviceResponse;
                }
                else
                {
                    AddNodesResponseMessage addNodesResponseMessage = InnerChannel.AddNodes(new AddNodesMessage(addNodesRequest));
                    if (addNodesResponseMessage == null || addNodesResponseMessage.AddNodesResponse == null)
                    {
                        throw new ServiceResultException(2148073472u);
                    }

                    addNodesResponse = addNodesResponseMessage.AddNodesResponse;
                    ClientBase.ValidateResponse(addNodesResponse.ResponseHeader);
                }

                results = addNodesResponse.Results;
                diagnosticInfos = addNodesResponse.DiagnosticInfos;
            }
            finally
            {
                RequestCompleted(addNodesRequest, addNodesResponse, "AddNodes");
            }

            return addNodesResponse.ResponseHeader;
        }
```

I want to add nodes while the OPC UA Server is running. Is there any example or library??
Regards

As i wrote above, I tried to add nodes by using AddNodes() method from client.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement the AddNodes service in OPCUA using the .NET Standard SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64292001/how-to-implement-the-addnodes-service-in-opcua-using-the-net-standard-sdk)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But it's the way to add nodes from the server side what i already succeed.
What i want to do is adding nodes from the client while the server is running.

Comment: If you implement AddNodes there, a client should be able to call it and so generate new nodes.

Comment: That's right. So i tried to use AddNodes() method but i failed to use it entirely. I want a example which used the AddNodes() method to add nodes. I can't handle the parameter of it. (RequestHeader, Addnodesitemcollection... etc)